# Fragment Back-stack android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three `Fragments`. On each button click, it will load the corresponding `Fragment`. If I again try to click on the button it will re-create a new `Fragment` and load, but instead of creating a new `Fragment` I need to show existing back-stack `Fragment`.

Code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener {
    private Frag1 frag1;
    private  Frag2 frag2;
    private  Frag3 frag3;
    Button one,two,three;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerViewComponent();
        registerClick();


    }

    private void registerClick() {
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void registerViewComponent() {
        one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
        two=(Button)findViewById(R.id.two);
        three=(Button)findViewById(R.id.three);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.one:
                frag1=new Frag1();
                frag3=new Frag3();
                frag2=new Frag2();

                fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


                Fragment fragment2 =        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Frag1");
                Log.v("Tag","Tagg::"+fragment2);
                if (fragment2 instanceof Frag1){
                    Log.v("If","IF::"+fragment2);
                }
                else {


                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.stack_frame,frag1,"Frag1").addToBackStack("Frag1");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }

                break;
            case R.id.two:
      frag2=new Frag2();

                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Frag2");
                Log.v("Tag","Tagg::"+fragment);
                if (fragment instanceof Frag2){
                    Log.v("If","IF::"+fragment);


                }
                else {

                    fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.stack_frame,frag2,"Frag2").addToBackStack("Frag2");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.three:
                frag3=new Frag3();
                Fragment fragment1 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Frag3");
                Log.v("Tag","Tagg::"+fragment1);
                if (fragment1 instanceof Frag3){
                    Log.v("If","IF::"+fragment1);


                }
                else {

                    fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.stack_frame,frag3,"Frag3").addToBackStack("Frag3");

                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }

                break;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: dont  create new object on button click, check if fragment has value or not

Comment: it contain value,how to display again that fragment on click without creating?

Answer (score 0):

```
Frag3 frag3;     
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_main);
  if (fragment instanceof Frag3) {
     frag3 = (Frag3) fragment;
  } else {
     frag3 = new Frag3();
  }
```

--------------OR---------------------

```
 Frag3 frag3 = new Frag3();  
 List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
 for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
   if(fragment instanceof Frag3){
    frag3 = (Frag3)fragment;
   }
 }
```

Then do fragment transaction

```
fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.stack_frame,frag3,"Frag3").addToBackStack("Frag3");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: its not displaying stack fragment onclick()

Comment: if i click again button 1 it should display fragment without creating again

Comment: First new instance of the fragment is created, then it will check the back stack if their is already an instance of the fragment exists, if it exists then it will replace new instance with the older instance and return that older insance, if it doesn't exists it will return u the new instance